# Has anyone else had Problem with Android 3.1 Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

OS: macOS Mojave 10.14
I did a fresh install of Android Studio 3.1.
I created an empty Activity, with just the default activity_main.xml
I defined an emulator to be Google Pixel 5.

When I push the run button. The emulator failed to start, and, pointed to the idea.log file.

This is what I found in the log that related to the emulator failing:

> 2021-10-21 23:34:57,864 [ 629351]   INFO -
> manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: dyld: Symbol not found:
> _vmnet_shared_interface_name_key 2021-10-21 23:34:57,864 [ 629351]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: Referenced from:
> /Users/objectman/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/qemu-system-i386
> (which was built for Mac OS X 11.1) 2021-10-21 23:34:57,864 [ 629351]
> INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: Expected in:
> /System/Library/Frameworks/vmnet.framework/Versions/A/vmnet

I've created dynamic libs before on other projects.
This looks to me like the emulator is expecting a newer
version of the vmnet dynamic lib.

Has anyone else had this problem ?
Has anyone else solved this problem.

Comment: I just started having this problem on my machine today. I'm on Mojave 10.14.6. I updated the Android SDK build tools and emulator (to 30.9.5) and SDK tools prior to seeing this issue but not sure if they are to blame or not.

Comment: Do you really mean Android Studio 3.1? That version is ancient (from 2018). Maybe you mean 2020.3.1 Arctic Fox instead.

Comment: i'm working with 2020.3.1 Arctic Fox and i have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I'm having this issue after upgrading.  Apple docs state that '_vmnet_shared_interface_name_key' is available 10.15+.  Will be rolling back for the time being but it would make sense for this dependency to be fixed by google.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vmnet/vmnet_shared_interface_name_key

Comment: Well, I ended up upgrading to Catalina and all is well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and i fixed it by downgrading the Emulator:

- 1. Download an old version of emulator (in my case i used **emulator-darwin_x64-7425822** [download from here](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-darwin_x64-742582.zip))
- 2. Replace the **emulator** folder you downloaded with the one in your sdk folder (should normally be here `~/Library/Android/sdk`)

You can also fix it by upgrading your macOS version to the latest one.